# How to handle UIApplicationDelegate methods in an UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I have a UIViewController on a tab of a tab based app, that hooks up UIApplicationDelegate. I'd like to handle app events by UIApplicationDelegate, but I don't get them in my UIViewController, its methods are not called.

What should I do beside hook up it in my UIViewController's interface declaration?

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController<UIApplicationDelegate>
@end
```

Other delegates are works, I can handle them, except this, UIApplication and its delegate should have some trivial 'trick', but I could not find.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need a class other than the app delegate to respond to the various application events, then have the other class register for the various application notifications.

For example, to deal with the app entering the background:

```
// Put this in the class that needs to deal with entering the background
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(backgrounding) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

See the docs for `UIApplication` for a list of all of the notifications.

Don't forget to remove the observer in the `dealloc` method of the class.

Comment: If it is the way to do it, then I would do something wrong: only thing I want to do to save my view's textbox's text to NSUserDefaults, when app terminates. So I am afraid it would not be in the controller's app delegate handled terminate event. But where?

Comment: Put this in the view controller that needs to save its state.

Comment: @Tom...do as said by rmaddy,then upon termination best practice is to save that text to database and retrieve it while launching the app again...